# Update div when click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this piece of code. i am trying to update the div with the class display whenever the a tag is click

```
var current = 0;

function nextPage() {
    current++;
    return current;
}

$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("a").click(function () {
        $(".display").text(nextPage());
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What wrong thing is happening now? Do you receive an error message or see some behavior that is relevant?

Comment: Remove the <!-- -->, they are not valid js comments

Comment: i see nothing wrong in the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtSMm/

Comment: The div does not update

Comment: did you check the fiddle link i posted ? It is updating fine

Comment: Do you load <a> dynamically using ajax? If <a> is loaded by ajax, the event handler may be not attached

Comment: You could use delegate event in case <a> is loaded by ajax. Check out [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Even if <a> is not loaded by ajax but is created dynamically by javascript, you code will not work. If that's your case, $.on also fix it

Comment: can you post your html here ? This js code working for me!

Answer (score 0):

In your code line

```
$(".display").text(nextPage());
```

`$(".display")` returns a set of elements. Your actual target element might not be the first therein. Use $.each to iterate over every one or use the id-selector to specify a single DOM-element.

---

**`.each()` example:** ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NezLv/2/))

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("a").click(function () {
        $(".display").each(function (index, element) {
            $(element).text(nextPage());
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

---

**id-selector example:** ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NezLv/3/))

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("a").click(function () {
        $("#display2").text(nextPage());
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that all dynamically inserted elements will have an event use `.on`.

[**This example on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wF2sh/)

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function () {
    $(".display").text(nextPage());
    return false;
});
```

Note: `<!-- comment -->` only works on HTML, for Javascript use `// comment` or `/* comment */`